# Query Sum by Shift in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables called `stop`, `detail`, and `shift`. I would like to do something so the result can like the image

[image]

I'm having hard time doing this, please help me.

I will appreciate it if you guys can help me on this :D

Thanks in advance

=============================================================

**Edit:**

Thanks for telling me what i have to do, so here is it

Table Stop:

1. VehicleID -> varchar
2. StopStart -> datetime
3. StopEnd -> datetime
4. Duration -> datetime ( StopEnd - StopStart)

Table Detail:

1. VehicleID -> varchar
2. State ( Have Idle and Drive ) -> varchar
3. StartTime -> datetime
4. StopTime -> datetime
5. Duration -> datetime ( StopTime - StartTime)

Table Shift:

1. NoShift -> int
2. In -> datetime (only take hours)
3. Out -> datetime (only take hours)

The `result` i `expect` from it:
one vehicle have 3 shift(1 2 3) and drive idle stop is the sum from duration that have from table stop and detail ( detail have state so it complicated ) and they must sum by shift with the time In and Out from table shift

i'm not an expert on query so, i don't know how to solve this problem, the query i'm making was no good, i have only tried to make shift base on stop table, but i don't know how to make join it with table shift

this is what i have tried

```
Select VehicleID,
Sum((select Duration from stop where DATEPART(hh,[StopStart]) >= 7 AND DATEPART(hh,[StopEnd]) <= 11)) AS Shift1,
Sum((select Duration from stop where DATEPART(hh,[StopStart]) >= 11 AND DATEPART(hh,[StopEnd]) <= 14)) AS Shift2,
Sum((select Duration from stop where DATEPART(hh,[StopStart]) >= 14 AND DATEPART(hh,[StopEnd]) <= 18)) AS Shift3
from Stop
Group By VehicleID
```

Comment: Screen shots will not make much difference . post some sample data and Relevant output

Comment: the sample data already on image :D
please click on it

Comment: it is not our duty to frame everything and serve on your platter

Comment: i think i have write this above 
"I'm having hard time for this, please help me i will appreciate it if you guys can help me on this :D"

because i have no solution on this, thats why i asking for solution here

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Irvan. If you want to get some useful advice from the other users, it's best to include your table structures, the code that you've already tried, a clear description of your problem, sample data, and expected output. You can find a more thorough description of how to write a good question here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not everyone can understand your problem and provide you with a solution based on the image. Please let us know what you have tried or where you are stuck. Help us to help you.

Comment: what is the different between table Stop and table Detail? looks like they have the same data. Only that table detail has one more column than table Stop

Comment: the diffrent is in state :D, detail have state that have data for drive and idle, and stop is a stand alone table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming starttime determines the shift and that drive/idle are always within one shift.

```
CREATE TABLE #Stop (
    VehicleId varchar(10)
   ,StopStart datetime
   ,StopEnd datetime
);

CREATE TABLE #Detail (
    VehicleId varchar(10)
   ,State varchar(10)
   ,StartTime datetime
   ,StopTime datetime
);

CREATE TABLE #Shift (
   Id int
  ,[In] datetime
  ,[Out] datetime
);

INSERT INTO #Stop 
VALUES ('a','7:00','11:00')
      ,('a','11:00','14:00')
      ,('b','7:00','7:00')
      ,('b','14:00','18:00');

INSERT INTO #Detail
VALUES ('a', 'Drive', '7:00', '11:00')
      ,('a', 'Idle', '11:00', '14:00')
      ,('b', 'Drive', '7:00', '7:00')
      ,('b', 'Idle', '14:00', '18:00');


INSERT INTO #Shift 
VALUES (1, '7:00', '11:00')
      ,(2, '11:00', '14:00')
      ,(3, '14:00', '18:00');


WITH DriveDetails AS (
    SELECT Detail.VehicleId
          ,Detail.State
          ,Shift.Id AS ShiftId
          ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, Detail.StartTime, Detail.StopTime)) AS DurationMinutes
    FROM #Detail AS Detail
         INNER JOIN #Shift AS Shift
             ON Detail.StartTime BETWEEN Shift.[In] AND Shift.[Out]
    GROUP BY Detail.VehicleId
            ,Detail.State
            ,Shift.Id
)
,Stop AS (
    SELECT Stop.VehicleId
          ,Shift.Id AS ShiftId
          ,SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, Stop.StopStart, Stop.StopEnd)) AS DurationMinutes
    FROM #Stop AS Stop
         INNER JOIN #Shift AS Shift
             ON Stop.StopStart BETWEEN Shift.[In] AND Shift.[Out]
    GROUP BY Stop.VehicleId
            ,Shift.Id
)
,VehicleShifts AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           Detail.VehicleId
          ,Shift.Id AS ShiftId
    FROM #Detail AS Detail
         CROSS JOIN #Shift AS Shift
)
SELECT VehicleShifts.VehicleId
      ,VehicleShifts.ShiftId
      ,CONVERT(time, DATEADD(minute, Drive.DurationMinutes, 0)) AS Drive
      ,CONVERT(time, DATEADD(minute, Idle.DurationMinutes, 0)) AS Idle
      ,CONVERT(time, DATEADD(minute, Stop.DurationMinutes, 0)) AS Stop
FROM VehicleShifts
     LEFT JOIN DriveDetails AS Drive
         ON Drive.VehicleId = VehicleShifts.VehicleId
            AND Drive.ShiftId = VehicleShifts.ShiftId 
            AND Drive.State = 'Drive'
     LEFT JOIN DriveDetails AS Idle
         ON Idle.VehicleId = VehicleShifts.VehicleId
            AND Idle.ShiftId = VehicleShifts.ShiftId 
            AND Idle.State = 'Idle'
     LEFT JOIN Stop 
         ON Stop.VehicleId = VehicleShifts.VehicleId
            AND Stop.ShiftId = VehicleShifts.ShiftId
```

Comment: i have tried this, but got error like this

Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type time is not a defined system type.

Comment: Remove the SQL2008 tag in your question and change to `datetime` (and start using a supported SQL server version. Support for SQL2005 ended 5 years ago).

Comment: thanks @adrianm, this really help me a lot, thanks for helping me solve this problem